# How to remove unigrams from word dictionary in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, word-cloud

I am trying to create a wordcloud with only bigrams in python. Now I have a dictionary as follows:

**Word_dict**

```
{'delivered later requested_delivered later requested': 0.07590105638848002,
 'delayed delivery_delayed delivery': 0.043280231684707335,
 'guidelines followed_guidelines followed': 0.04056653336980544,
 'delayed pickup_delayed pickup': 0.02733236942769188,
 'delivered later requested_delayed delivery': 0.023815416411579027,
 'delayed delivery_delivered later requested': 0.02332477975624476,
 'guidelines followed_delivered later requested': 0.02131881396186928,
 'delivered later requested_guidelines followed': 0.020793441968104277,
 'delayed pickup_delayed delivery': 0.020619765275950556,
 'delayed delivery_guidelines followed': 0.01998150343228563,
 'delayed delivery_delayed pickup': 0.019464815273128308,
 'guidelines followed_delayed delivery': 0.018900366023628715,
 'delivered later requested_delayed pickup': 0.01870932166225962,
 'delayed pickup_delivered later requested': 0.0185660383912328,
 'guidelines followed_delayed pickup': 0.015148949473108336,
 'delayed pickup_guidelines followed': 0.01475383499845862,
 'super user activity fom_super user activity fom': 0.010490072206084763}
```

I need to remove the unigrams or words without underscore from dictionary.How Can do it.

**Expected Output**

```
{' requested_delivered ': 0.07590105638848002,
 'delivery_delayed ': 0.043280231684707335,
 'followed_guidelines': 0.04056653336980544,
 'pickup_delayed ': 0.02733236942769188,
 ' requested_delayed ': 0.023815416411579027}
```

How to do it?

**Mycode**

```
def preprocess(x):
    x = re.sub('[^a-z\s]', '', x.lower())                  # get rid of noise
    x = [w for w in x.split() if w not in set(newstopwords)]  # remove stopwords
    return ' '.join(x)

data['Clean_addr'] = data['Reason Code Level 1'].apply(preprocess)

# setup and score the bigrams using the raw frequency.
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(text_content)
bigram_measures = BigramAssocMeasures()
scored = finder.score_ngrams(bigram_measures.raw_freq)

# By default finder.score_ngrams is sorted, however don't rely on this default behavior.
# Sort highest to lowest based on the score.
scoredList = sorted(scored, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

# word_dict is the dictionary we'll use for the word cloud.
# Load dictionary with the FOR loop below.
# The dictionary will look like this with the bigram and the score from above.
# word_dict = {'bigram A': 0.000697411,
#             'bigram B': 0.000524882}

word_dict = {}

listLen = len(scoredList)

# Get the bigram and make a contiguous string for the dictionary key. 
# Set the key to the scored value. 
for i in range(listLen):
    word_dict['_'.join(scoredList[i][0])] = scoredList[i][1]



# -----
```

Comment: If you plan to remove all words that only contain letters, use `re.sub(r'\s*(?<!\S)[^\W\d_]+(?!\S)', '', s).strip()`. If you want regular word boundaries, use `print(re.sub(r'\s*\b[^\W\d_]+\b', '', s).strip())`. See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/ozNpUi).

Comment: In the expected output, should the spaces be kept before and after `'delivery_delayed '`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can guarantee from your data set that there is only zero or one underscore-containing phrase in the entire set:

```
# starting from scoredList in the example above (had to add scored.items()) so that you're iterating over key/value pairs
scoredList = sorted(scored.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

new_data = {}
for key, value in scoredList:
    words = [word for word in key.split(' ') if '_' in word]
    if len(words) == 1:
        new_data[words[0]] = value
    elif len(words) > 1:
        raise ValueError('oh no...')

print(new_data)
```

Comment: Edited to be a completely self-contained example; what error did you see?

Comment: Actually, looking more closely at your data set, it appears that there are some duplicates...what would the intended behavior be? (I see `delivery_delayed` appearing at least twice, for example)

Comment: Looks like `scoredList` isn't a `dict`; fixed the line where you sort by values and changed the `for` loop accordingly.

Comment: The dulplicates are intended behaviour

Comment: I could think of a few ways of handling it...grab only the first value? The last value? Sum them all up? What is the requirement?

Comment: the requirement is to include only the bigrams i.e words with underscore that are obtained using bigram collocator.

Comment: `delivery_delayed` appears twice in your data set, on the second line with a value of 0.043280231684707335, and on the eleventh line with a value of 0.019464815273128308. Was the intent to discard the value associated with the eleventh line because you already had `delivery_delayed` appear earlier in the data set?

Comment: No actually my requirement is just to remove all unigrams from each keys from the dict,duplicates would not be a problem.